# menu-mini panels: removing anchor tag from menu item

Tags: routes, navigation

I've used the [menu-minipanel](http://drupal.org/project/menu_minipanels) module to set-up some mega menus. The main menu items are set (using the module UI) to show a minipanel with my various menu blocks/nodes.

However I don't want the 1st level menu items themselves to point anywhere, and since I've used the Menu Minipanel option to allow for a click to reveal the minipanel I was forced to use the [Special Menu Items module](http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) to generate a "#" as an href.

However the problem I'm having now is that when the user clicks on the menu items to open the megamenu, the '#' href takes them to the top of the page.

Can anyone suggest any options here?

[Here's the site](http://drupal.scienceworld.ca) I'm working on presently as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some jquery here, by capturing click event of this menu item, and returning false.

```
$("<selector>").click(function(){
   return false;
});
```

Or try this

```
$("<selector>").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();   
});
```